# How to avoid opening duplicate files in new windows in gedit?

Tags: gedit

Having already opened several text files with each in one tab in a window, 
now open another text file,

1. gedit sometimes creates another window instead of a session under
   the current window. I wonder if it is possible to control whether to
   open the next file under the current window, or in a new one?
2. if the text file has already been opened, gedit sometimes open it
   again in another window, and ask me if I want to edit or not. I was
   wondering how to make gedit not to open a file already opened?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the same as this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti/79295#79295

Comment: close, but I asked much earlier than that one.

Comment: it doesnt really matter who asked first  - we can merge the answers to either Q - what I need to know is, if that linked Q is the same in your eyes and if so, does the answer do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you **open the file from gedit** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, or use the big 'Open' button shown) it will open the new file in a new tab. If you open new files from Nautilus (or another file manager), it may or may not. Also, as @harisibrahimkv points out, files with different permissions/users will be handled differently.

[image: gedit file open dialog]

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happen if you are trying to open files with different permissions. As in, if you open a file with sudo while gedit is already open, it might open in another window.

Comment: BUt in all my cases, the files have the same permission