# gedit opens different window though it should not

Tags: 12.04, unity, command-line, nautilus, gedit

It's a follow-up of [Why does gedit keep randomly opening new instances when opening files from nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/) On Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity:

- I double click on a text file on the desktop or through Nautilus. Gedit opens a new instance. That's fine.
- I open gnome-terminal on the same display/screen. I type "gedit", it opens a new different window on the same display/screen.

Why is that? I tried to log "is_in_viewport" referenced in the above question, but I didn't get useful information. What is missing in the terminal environment so that gedit opens a new window though it should not as I'm on the same screen/display and the border condition is not true.

Note that in the terminal, echo $DISPLAY returns :0 and echo $SCREEN returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sad that nobody investigated my problem! Anyway, I have redo the investigation and I figured out that DISPLAY=:0 from the terminal while DISPLAY=:0.0 when it's launched from the Gnome/Unity environment.

export DISPLAY=:0.0 in the terminal fixes the problem. i will try to file a bug to Gnome as :0 should be interpreted as :0.0.

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700851