# gedit will not open a new tab for when opening a second document and onwards

Tags: command-line, window, gedit, settings, document

I am puzzled by the behaviour of gedit. I have three different machines and while in two of them I have the desired results (after opening a document with gedit the next ones are opened in tabs), in another machine I don't. I have tried the suggestions in:

[Configure Gedit to always open documents in new tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960589/configure-gedit-to-always-open-documents-in-new-tab)

[Why does gedit keep randomly opening new instances when opening files from nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti/79295#79295)

[gedit opens different window though it should not](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293163/gedit-opens-different-window-though-it-should-not?rq=1)

I tried to find inspiration from other questions like:

[gedit open second file onwards in a new window. Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191977/gedit-open-second-file-onwards-in-a-new-window-ubuntu-19-10)

Of course I compared what looks like relevant files (/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop --and-- /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop) from my working machines to the files in the target machine, did many trials...all of them ended up in failure.

It is like gedit will either "does not matter what" open in a new tab or "does not matter what" in a new window...

I run Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I was sad I got no help but I can understand gedit is a bit frustrating on this topic. I tried several things...with no luck, thus increasing my frustration. However, today I realised that even if when running gedit like in:

```
gedit test.sh &
```

and I did not get any errors, when saving files or opening new files from the GUI I did get some:

```
(gedit:46958): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: XX:YY:ZZ.382: g_dbus_proxy_new_sync: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
(gedit:46958): dconf-WARNING **: XX:YY:ZZ.403: failed to commit changes to dconf: No s'ha pogut executar el procés fill «dbus-launch» (El fitxer o directori no existeix)
(gedit:46958): dconf-WARNING **: XX:YY:ZZ.572: failed to commit changes to dconf: No s'ha pogut executar el procés fill «dbus-launch» (El fitxer o directori no existeix)
(gedit:46958): dconf-WARNING **: XX:YY:ZZ.461: failed to commit changes to dconf: No s'ha pogut executar el procés fill «dbus-launch» (El fitxer o directori no existeix)
(gedit:46958): dconf-WARNING **: XX:YY:ZZ.462: failed to commit changes to dconf: No s'ha pogut executar el procés fill «dbus-launch» (El fitxer o directori no existeix)
(gedit:46958): dconf-WARNING **: XX:YY:ZZ.462: failed to commit changes to dconf: No s'ha pogut executar el procés fill «dbus-launch» (El fitxer o directori no existeix)
```

I could save or open files as I needed but I wondered if these messages had any connection with the problem posted above and it did. Searching on how to get rid off the messages above:

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

seems to have solved the problem and I do not get those annoying messages anymore. Two birds with on stone! Problem solved!