# avconv assert error mpah.frame_size when trying to convert WAV to MP3 under 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04, 64-bit, ffmpeg, avconv

My objective is to convert a WAV file to MP3 on 14.04 (64-bit).

The wav file is "Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono" and is known to good.   It plays fine with `aplay`, also converts successfully with ffmpeg on OS X.

Thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04), I learned ffmpeg is not part of the standard 14.04 repo, and that `avconv` is the replacement.

I installed that with `sudo apt-get install libav-tools`

Here's the error with aconv when I try to convert wav to mp3:

```
user@L114:/tmp$ avconv -i sound_2014-06-01_08-51-31.wav s1.mp3
avconv version 9.13-6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on May  9 2014 13:34:03 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[wav @ 0x150cd40] max_analyze_duration reached
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'sound_2014-06-01_08-51-31.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:55.04, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Assertion mpah.frame_size >= (32 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 100) failed at /build/buildd/libav-9.13/libavformat/mp3enc.c:198
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How may I fix this?  Or is this a bug to be logged?

It's not impossible some incompatibilities exist on the box, due to other packages previously installed in attempts to get `pyaudio` working.  That's what created the wav file.

Any other info needed to help diagnose this?

P.S. Before I learned of avconv this morning, I did manage to download a pre-built version of ffmpeg (as tarball, not an installable package).  However, the converted file was no good and sounds like really loud "white noise".  I'm including the console output from ffpmeg below, in case this offers any additional clues.

Please know my preference IS to solve this with avconv, since that's the supported go-forward tool.

```
user@L114:/tmp$ ffmpeg -i sound_2014-06-01_08-51-31.wav s1.mp3
ffmpeg version N-63624-g4ba8560 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 31 2014 05:37:43 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit --extra-cflags='-I/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/ffmpeg-static/64bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 87.100 / 52. 87.100
  libavcodec     55. 65.100 / 55. 65.100
  libavformat    55. 42.100 / 55. 42.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from 'sound_2014-06-01_08-51-31.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:55.04, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 's1.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf55.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 16000 Hz, mono, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.65.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     513kB time=00:02:55.07 bitrate=  24.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:513kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.042823%
```

========

**UPDATE 8-Jun-2014:**

Discovered that ffmpeg is working fine after all.   Aquarius Power's suggestion to use mplayer was successful.

I believe my mistake is in expecting aplay to play MP3 files, when my "Available formats:" shows only these:

```
- U8
- S16_LE
- S16_BE
- S32_LE
- S32_BE
- FLOAT_LE
- FLOAT_BE
- MU_LAW
- A_LAW
```

So ffmpeg DOES WORK, and mplayer DOES PLAY the mp3's.

However, I'd like to focus to getting an answer for the **avconv assert problem**.

For those wanting sample files, see Dropbox folder [avconv](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zzaac9g4550eh0v/AAD7ERjIx4rZOZb0VbrnqVQ2a) :

```
sound.wav           - source wav file of several piano notes & silence
avconv_output.txt   - console output running avconv
avconv.mp3          - 0 byte mp3 output file
ffmpeg_output.txt   - console output running ffmpeg
ffmpeg.mp3          - working ffmpeg mp3 output file
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: it happens too with `Playing Sparc Audio 'audioFile.wav' : Signed 16 bit Big Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono`

Comment: try to play your `s1.mp3` created with `ffmpeg` with `mplayer`, it worked here for mine where `aplay` failed!

Comment: we can try to understand what went wrong by reading the .c code following this tip to get it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti

Comment: `play` from `sox` also works where `aplay` failed!

Comment: Please provide the input file so I can attempt to duplicate the issue with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Happens to me when trying to convert `.CAF` files to `.mp3` using `avconv`.

Comment: How was the input file created? I'm still interested in attempting to duplicate this (and @Exeleration-G your CAF input would be useful too).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the input file was created with python.  Please see my updated question with a link to a folder containing a sample wav file.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I was only concerned about `ffmpeg`, not the buggy `avconv`, and I can confirm that it works fine in `ffmpeg`. As for `avconv` you'll have to either file a bug report upstream if you can reproduce it using their latest version, or if not, then file a bug report to Ubuntu. Or just use `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded to 14.04 and ran into the same problem.  Adding "-b 256k" fixed it for me (although the resulting MP3 was generated with a 160Kbps bitrate rather than the original 256Kbps rate).