# How to open a *.pdf in an already existing instance of Okular (independent of in which workspace that instance resides)?

Tags: kde, pdf, workspaces

`acroread` and `qpdfview` already perform as desired: if an instance of `acroread` or `qpdfview`, resp., is already running this instance will open any pdf files, **irrespective of the workspace** from which these files are "launched".

Now here's the catch: **`okular`**, alas, behaves differently:

"launching" (read: opening) a pdf file from a given workspace will create **a new instance** of `okular` **in that workspace**, *unless* that particular workspace already has an instance of `okular` up and running.

Anything I can add to `/usr/bin/okular` to do the trick?

`man okular` doesn't give any hints to this and also from within `okular` I see no indicative option in the native settings.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/355761/16023) may work to distinguish between multiple displays but not workspaces...

Comment: I tested it, and I get the same behaviour. With Settings > Configure Okular… > General > Program Features > Open new files in tabs, I open pdfs in the same instance, unless opening from a different virtual desktop (with Dolphin). However, it works when initiating from a different activity. This sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: `acroread` has the `-openInNewInstance` option, `qpdfview` the `--unique` option, see the respective `man` pages and `*.desktop` files. `okular` OTOH seems to offer nothing along those lines... (? so either need to go deep into `okular` code, recompile, etc or apply some other trick (unity, compiz, ...) ?)

Comment: Okular has a global option in its settings though. Like I said, I think it's a bug, since it works fine for pdfs opened in the same virtual desktop.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. Hope this gets fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I recently wanted to have the same functionality. Here is the simplest solution I could find:

Open Okular GUI. Navigate to **Settings** > **Configure Okular**. In **General**, under **Program Features**, check the *'Open new files in tabs'* option. Click **Apply**. Click **OK**.

Then on your terminal, run `okular file1.pdf file2.pdf fileN.pdf`.

That code should open all your files in the same Okular window in different tabs.  This method works across folders.

Comment: My question was *[workspace](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html)*-related. Your answer and my question don't overlap.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty then please edit your question to make that clear. It does sound like you're trying to open in tabs. You might want to emphasize that your issue is when you're opening something from the file manager and not from okular and that it is about workspaces.

Comment: @terdon Disagree. See title, tag *and* content.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty if at least two people have had trouble understanding your question, that's a pretty good indication that it isn't quite as clear as you think it is. Change it or not, it's completely up to you, but you're more likely to get a helpful answer if you do.

Comment: @terdon edited.