# How to prevent Gedit from opening a launched file in an instance on another workspace

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces, gedit

Using Ubuntu 21.04 with pure Gnome Shell 3.38.

Consider this example scenario: I have 2 workspaces open, workspace-1 and workspace-2. In workspace-2, the Gedit app is open. In workspace-1, the Gedit app is not open.

While in workspace-1, I enter Nautilus app and double-click on a saved Gedit text file. Gedit opens the file but auto-moves to workspace-2 to present the opened file. WTHeck! Why isn't it opening Gedit in the workspace I am in? What is the point of workspaces if you can't create the stuff you want to work with in that workspace?

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug in 21.04.  I am using GNOME 3.36 in 20.04 and I can't seem to duplicate your issue.

Comment: Not a bug, but how it works/is designed: by default the new file is opened in an existing instance. Still, I agree that for users who which to separate workspaces it is desired to have a new window opened in the current workspace. There might be tricks to change that behaviour, so useful question indeed!

Comment: @vanadium Well, if it is not a bug, then it would be useful for the OP to file one anyways for a feature if this cannot be done in the newer version.

Comment: @Terrance Interesting! Indeed, in 20.04, it behaves differently, the way you describe and the OP wants!

Comment: Interesting answer here, likely pinpointing where this behaviour may have been changed in recent gedit versions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti?rq=1

Comment: Did you try `gedit --new-window filename.txt` or `gedit -s filename.txt` ?

Comment: `gedit --new-window filename` does open in a new window, but this is not the expected behaviour. The behaviour should be "new-window" *if* "there is not another open window in the present workspace". If it is not a bug, it is a very bad design.

Comment: This gnome shell extension apparently could do the job: https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/   However, the option "isolate workspaces" is not available in ubuntu 22.04 and reports `Managed by GNOME Multitasking's application switcher`. However under `Settings --> Multitasking` there is not an option to isolate workspaces ...

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has been added with the migration to Wayland only, instead of keeping support for X11, as discussed [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/issues/177).

But because this has been bugging me too, and I still use X11, I reverted the commits in question:
Similar as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti?rq=1) explained, you need to revert commits [C1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/commit/9a74ce01091bcf6fb47f45e1f0bb5a673971841a), [C2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/commit/fca08ebc113fe8e3d06713379935e0a781284b7d) and finally, most importantly [C3](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/commit/d0728e7d0c3e7fdc58f03f0af4e0ce64eb7aef6e).

My patchfile for Gedit 40.1 you can find in my [Gentoo overlay](https://gitlab.com/f14h/f14h_overlay/-/blob/master/app-editors/gedit/files/40.1-restore-workspace-awareness.patch).

Comment: Same issue here. Ubuntu 22.04, gedit 41.0. Even if I set <pre>gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui show-tabs-mode 'never'</pre> the new window opens in the other worskapce. gedit -s filename works. But it is not a solution in my opinione.